# Downgrade linux kernel in lubuntu

Tags: 14.04, kernel, lubuntu

I am using lubuntu 14.04. I want to downgrade the kernel. It was pretty simple in ubuntu 14.04 downloading and opening in software center, but in lubuntu that is not working. I have installed it using package installer but when I restart my computer I see same kernel. 
Can any one guide me how to downgrade linux kernal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press an hold shift just before grub starts (if your PC does not show grub at boot), choose "advanced options for ubuntu" and you will see all the previously installed kernels you have have, just choose the one you want.

Not listed ? Google the version you need, install it and then use the grub menu to select it.

[image]

Comment: i cant see this screen at start .. I am using lubuntu. i use to see this when i had ubuntu. I have downloaded kernel and then have GDebi Package Installer, and after restarting i see the same kernel .. not the one i want to install. and i cant find advanced options any where in lubuntu

Comment: I am able to solve this .... from shift command you mentioned... Thanks alot @mark kirby

Comment: one thing i am noticing, that after i select the kernel, my mouse stop working if i choose my desired kernel .., but if i choose the latest kernel that doesn't happen, any idea why this is happening ?

Comment: Tell me what kernel version you downgraded to (the one where mouse wont work)

Comment: I want to use 3.13.0-34 linux kernel..  it works and i can change it from grub menu as you suggested but the mouse doesn't work when i am at desktop and the other kernel is 3.13.0-53 where the mouse works fine

Comment: From the latest kernel you have installed (3.13.0-53), open a terminal and run `sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-3.13.0-34-generic linux-headers-3.13.0-34-generic` now reboot to 3.13.0-34 and mouse should work.

Comment: done and its working, super thanks @mark kirby ..

Answer (score 0):

You should boot an older kernel, then remove the one you no longer need (I assume that is the latest one). You can use the command line interface of `apt-get` if the GUI programs are lacking and should remove the appropriate `linux-image-*` and `linux-headers-*` packages.

**Update:** To get to the GRUB menu, change your GRUB configuration in `/etc/default/grub`. These keys should be modified:

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=false
```

This sets the menu as always visible, with a 10 second timeout.

Comment: how to boot older kernel, thats the question .. i cant see grub screen

Comment: See my update in the answer